# python loguru output to stderr and a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, loguru

I have the following line that configures my logger instance

```
logger.add(sys.stderr, level=log_level, format="<green>{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS zz}</green> | <level>{level: <8}</level> | <yellow>Line {line: >4} ({file}):</yellow> <b>{message}</b>", colorize=True, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)
```

I want to configure my logger to use the above, and also output to a file, so that when I call logger.whatever() it outputs to the terminal and to a log file

This way, if I'm doing dev work and running the file directly, I can see the output in my terminal, and when the code is being run on a server by a cronjob, it can log to a file

I don't understand the whole concept of the "sinks" so sorry if this is an easy question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the context of logging, a "sink" refers to an output destination for log records. It can be a stream (such as `sys.stderr` or `sys.stdout`), a file path, or any custom function that accepts the logged message an input. See [documentation](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#sink) for more details.

Using Loguru, you can add as many sinks as you like. This means that in your case, you can have two sinks: one writing to `sys.stderr` and another one writing to `file.log`.

```py
log_level = "DEBUG"
log_format = "<green>{time:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS zz}</green> | <level>{level: <8}</level> | <yellow>Line {line: >4} ({file}):</yellow> <b>{message}</b>"
logger.add(sys.stderr, level=log_level, format=log_format, colorize=True, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)
logger.add("file.log", level=log_level, format=log_format, colorize=False, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)
```

Each time a message is logged with `logger.info()` for example, it will be sent to each of the added sinks and processed based on the the corresponding configuration.

Comment: I'm revisiting this problem and am encountering a problem where error messages are being shown to the terminal, but not to the log file. The regular log messages appear in both my terminal and the log file, but any error only outputs to my terminal and not the log file. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch There's no reason for it. It looks like a sink configuration problem (due to a filter?). It's difficult to give more details without seeing your code.

Comment: I've created a post for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77669753/python-loguru-outputs-error-to-terminal-but-not-to-log-file